# Move element up a bit

Tags: css, vue.js, sass

I need to position the number "01 / 04" like this image

[image]

So far I got this

[image]

Code structure is like this in vue js, so far:

```
<img id="theZoomImage" sizes="100vw" :srcset="imageSources(images[current])" :src="imageSource(images[current])" />
<div class="product-images-popup-bar">
    <div class="product-images-popup-number">
        <span class="product-images-popup-child_num">0{{current+1}}</span>
        <span class="product-images-popup-parent_num">0{{totalImageNum()}}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="product-images-popup-pagination">pagination</div>
</div>
```

css so far:

```
.product-images-popup-bar {
    position: absolute;
    left: 5vw;
}

.product-images-popup-number {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
}

.product-images-popup-child_num {
    line-height: 1;
    color: #191919;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue Condensed', HelveticaNeue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

    font-size: 30px;
    font-size: 7vw;
}

.product-images-popup-parent_num {
    line-height: 1;
    color: #191919;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue Condensed', HelveticaNeue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

    font-size: 15px;
    font-size: 4vw;
    padding: 1px 0 0 4px;
}

.product-images-popup-parent_num:before {
    content: '/';
    padding-right: 5px;
}

.product-images-popup-pagination {

}
```

The **goal** is moving the numbers + pagination **up a bit** in different device size.

I am thinking to get "product-images-popup-bar" coordinate, then subtract some values, then position it. **Not sure how to get the coordinate though.**

Comment: can you please put some dummy images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give the elements you want moved up slightly a position of `relative` and then `top` minus the amount you want

for example

```
.product-images-popup-number {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    position: relative;
    top: -5px;
}
```

and then obviously use media queries to adjust it as you please